mongodb and nextjs connetion problem GET http://localhost:3000/api/movies 404
i created a cluster in mongodb atlas it had some dummy data like this
"sample_mflix(movies(title, runtime, year))"
and i want to display it on a table, here is the code for the component that do the display:
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'


interface Movie{
  _id:any
  title: string
  year:number
  runtime: number
}

function DataTable() {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState<Movie[]>([])
  useEffect(()=>{
    async function fetchMovies() {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('/api/movies')
        if(!response.ok){
          console.log(response)
        }
        const data: Movie[] = await response.json()
        setMovies(data) 
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('failed to fetch',error)
      }
    }
    fetchMovies()
  }, [])

  
 
    
      return (
        <div className="p-4">
          <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-4">Movie List</h1>
          <div className="overflow-x-auto">
            <table className="table-auto w-full border-collapse border border-gray-300">
              <thead>
                <tr className="bg-gray-200">
                  <th className="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 text-left">Title</th>
                  <th className="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 text-left">Year</th>
                  <th className="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 text-left">Runtime</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {movies.map((movie, index) => (
                  <tr key={index} className="even:bg-gray-100">
                    <td className="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2">{movie.title}</td>
                    <td className="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2">{movie.year}</td>
                    <td className="border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2">{movie.runtime}</td>
                  </tr>
                ))}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
}

export default DataTable

this is the db connetion :
import { config } from 'dotenv';

config();

const MONGODB_URI = process.env.MONGODB_URI;



if (!MONGODB_URI) {
    throw new Error('Please define the MONGODB_URI environment variable');
}

interface Cached {
    conn: typeof mongoose | null;
    promise: Promise<typeof mongoose> | null;
}

let cached: Cached = (global as any).mongoose;

if (!cached) {
    cached = (global as any).mongoose = { conn: null, promise: null };
}

async function connectToDatabase() {
    if (cached.conn) {
        return cached.conn;
    }

    if (!cached.promise) {
        cached.promise = mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI as string).then((mongoose) => {
            return mongoose;
        });
    }
    cached.conn = await cached.promise;
    return cached.conn;
}

export default connectToDatabase;

and this is the api/movies.ts :
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import connectToDatabase from '../../utils/db';
import mongoose, { Document, Model } from 'mongoose';

interface IMovie extends mongoose.Document {
    title: string
    year:number
    runtime: number
}

// Define a schema for movies
const movieSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    year: { type: Number, required: true },
    releaseYear: { type: Number, required: true },
});

// Create a model for movies
const Movie: Model<IMovie> = mongoose.models.Movie || mongoose.model<IMovie>('Movie', movieSchema);

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
    await connectToDatabase();

    try {
        const movies = await Movie.find({});
        res.status(200).json(movies);
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to fetch movies' });
    }
}


ive tried everything but two errors keeps poping up
D:\web dev 2\next-te…ts\dataTable.tsx:17 
 GET http://localhost:3000/api/movies 404 (Not Found)
fetchMovies @   D:\web dev 2\next-te…ts\dataTable.tsx:17
DataTable.useEffect @   D:\web dev 2\next-te…ts\dataTable.tsx:27

and this one:
failed to fetch SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON

the response.ok = false

The first error you get 404 status code, that means route is not found. I'm gonna assume that you're using nextjs pages directory based on the syntax for defining api route. The api file needs to be inside pages/api/ directory. The second error you get is invalid json, do a console.log of the data you receive from database before res.json call. See what is the data you're getting

@Inder no im using app router

Your syntax for api routes is wrong then. Refer to these docs

its app/api/movies/route.ts @Inder
